# AWK remove one line?

Tags: awk

This is my uptime

```
uptime=`uptime|grep days|awk '{print$3,$4}'`
```

But it displays now: `23 days,`

I want to remove the `,` at the end.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: I can not reproduce the comma. Also your `grep` seems useless.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
uptime | awk -F'[, ]' '{print $3,$4}'
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
uptime | awk '/days/ { printf "%s%s",$3,substr($4,1,length($4)-1) ; }'
```

a sample test, ubuntu 14.04.1,

```
mybox $  uptime
 14:36:13 up 2 days, 23:41,  2 users,  load average: 0,17, 0,18, 0,14
mybox $  x=$(uptime | awk '/days/ { printf "%s%s",$3,substr($4,1,length($4)-1) ; }' )
mybox $  echo $x
2days
mybox $
```

Comment: Thanks but gnouc solution seems far easier for me to understand so I will go for that one. nevertheless appreciated the help.

Answer (score 1):

You may prefer to parse the uptime pseudofile directly like this:

```
uptime="$(( `cat /proc/uptime  | cut -f1 -d.` / 86400 )) days"
```

In the case uptime is less than 1 day it will display "0 days" instead of nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The `grep` is not needed as the `uptime` command only displays one line:

```
$ uptime
 1:15PM  up 2 days, 14:04, 1 user, load averages: 1.12, 1.12, 1.08
```

or

```
$ uptime
 1:24PM  up 8 mins, 1 user, load averages: 1.27, 1.17, 0.62
```

Assuming you'd like to extract the bit between the `up` the first comma (`2 days` or `8 mins` respectively in the two examples above):

```
$ uptime | sed 's/^.*up \([^,]*\).*$/\1/'
19 mins
```

The sed script `s/^.*up \([^,]*\).*$/\1/` will substitute the whole input line with the string between `up␣` and the first comma.